# Google places api text search issue

Tags: android, google-places-api, text-search

If I use 50,000 meter radius in my query I get the results but very near by places get omitted.
if I type same keyword in google maps results are completely different.

but results are exactly same if I keep radius to 1000 meters why so ?
Can anyone help me understand this ?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=19.9525768,73.7351819&radius=1000&query=atm&sensor=true&key=your_key

I would really appreciate if any could explain why this is happening and how i can get very near by places with 50,000 meter radius.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by increasing the `radius`? If you specify a `radius` then the results are ranked by prominence, not distance, so if you set the `radius = 50000`, you could return places that are more prominent than the places nearby (<1000m from) your location. This is why changing the `radius` is changing the results.

If you want a place close to your location, then either keep the radius low (like you have when you specified `radius=1000`) or omit radius completely and use `rankby=distance`.

See the docs: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: i want show all places inside 50 km radius. now if use rankby=distance request will give me next page token using which i can fecth more 20 results but google only provide 2 next page token that results which gives 60 records in total and this covers only 4-5 km radius approx.

Comment: to slove this issue i can use pagination and increase radius when user hit last item in list and then avoid duplicate entries. but will require too many api calls ... what i want is optimal solution to slove this issue –